# Flutter - How to sync two or more PageControllers

Tags: flutter

In `Flutter` I can´t assing the same `PageController` to many `PageView`. So in need to use two or more `PageController`s.

I need to synchronize my `ViewPage`s so that when I slide one another it also slides

**How can I sync two or more `PageController` or `PageView`?**

What I want is every `PageView` can control others `PageView` make them all sync no matter which slide.

So if a have **A**, **B** and **C** `PageView` and I slide **A**  then **B** and **C** slides as well... if I slide **B** then **A** and **C** slides... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference https://github.com/braulio94/menu_flutter 
The trick is use NotificationListener to listen ScrollUpdateNotification 
and compare two page

```
_backgroundPageController.page != _pageController.page
```

code snippet at line 183

```
new NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
            if (notification.depth == 0 &&
                notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
              selectedIndex.value = _pageController.page;
              if (_backgroundPageController.page != _pageController.page) {
                _backgroundPageController.position
                    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                    .jumpToWithoutSettling(_pageController.position.pixels /
                    _kViewportFraction);
              }
              setState(() {});
            }
            return false;
          }
```

full code 
https://github.com/braulio94/menu_flutter/blob/master/lib/screens/pager.dart

[image]

Comment: In that case only one PageView can control the others. What I want is every PageView can control others PageView make them all sync no matter which slide.

Comment: In this case NotificationListener listen all ScrollUpdateNotification of PageView even TabBar , so you can keep all pageController.page and compare their value

Answer (score 1):

To sync two pageviews (in case you want to use different viewfractions for example)
create two controllers, upper with view fraction 0,7 and bottom with 1.0
Now to sync add listener to upper and get current scroll offset value.

```
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
       _controller_upper = new PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7);
    _controller_bottom = new PageController();
    _controller.addListener(_onScroll);
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    scrollValue = _controller.page;
    //page returns value between 0 to 1 for 1st page, 1 to 2 for second and s on, need to multiply it by screen width
    _controller_bottom.jumpTo(scrollValue*MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. When you create controllers you can add listeners for each of. In every listener you should describe logic for another controller.

To be more clear I will describe in more detail. If necessary, you can combine the logic into one method, but it will be less clear.

```
 int _previousPage = 0;
  bool _isController1 = false;
  bool _isController2 = false;

  void resetMoveInfo(){
      _isController1 = false;
      _isController2 = false;
  }

     void _onController1Scroll() {
        if (_isController2)
          return;

        _isController1 = true;
        if (_controller1.page.toInt() == _controller1.page) {
          _previousPage = _controller1.page.toInt();
          resetMoveInfo();
        }

        _controller2.position
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            .jumpToWithoutSettling(_controller1.position.pixels * _viewPortFraction);
      }

void _onController2Scroll() {
        if (_isController1)
          return;

        _isController2 = true;
        if (_controller2.page.toInt() == _controller2.page) {
          _previousPage = _controller2.page.toInt();
          resetMoveInfo();
        }

        _controller1.position
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            .jumpToWithoutSettling(_controller2.position.pixels / _viewPortFraction);
      }
```

When you initialize your controller you should add listener for each of them

```
  _controller1 = PageController(
      initialPage: _previousPage,
      keepPage: false,
      viewportFraction: 1)
    ..addListener(_onController1Scroll);
```